What instrument can we hear during these 3 seconds?
Here is a song by Johnny Flynn. Could you help me to identify the instrument used from 1'28 to 1'31?
Thanks

Welcome, but sorry. This site isn't for instrument identification, so the question will close soon.

Sorry, but this question is not on-topic because it is asking to identify a particular piece of music, see: What topics can I ask about here?.
However, you can try asking in our chat room: The Practice Room.

Sounds like a highly processed violin or other bowed instrument.
